# How to Show only some records when page loads in firebase and when I scroll it have to show some limit records till total count of records in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am Using Recyclerview and for Displaying records Using Firebase

```
ref= new Firebase("URL");
jokesQuery = ref.orderByKey().startAt(0).limitToLast(20);
jokesQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        scheduleCallModellist=new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            list.add(postSnapshot.getValue());
        }
    }
});
```

I have implemented addOnScrollListener and in that I do know how to retrieve other values of Firebase. Can you Help me with this.

I have to display some 20 records when I scroll and whenever I scroll some 20 records have to show till the total count exceeds.

Comment: Implementing infinite scroll on Firebase Database is a quite complex topic. There are quite a few options/steps to get from "showing the last 20" to allowing the user to scroll up and load/display the additional items. Did you try anything more yet?

Comment: I am able to get last 10 records by using this query                    jokesQuery = ref.orderByKey().startAt("").limitToLast(limit); but in the scroll listener not able to get other records

Comment: @  user3682203 , I am sorry, I removed my answer because, I think, it is incorrect.

Comment: startAt() and endAt() have another meaning rather than we thought, try to read the documentation to understand that https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

Comment: I have tried all possibility but am not able to get the result and StartAt and limitToLast does not working correctly.